# Eclipse gradle build model fails due to invalid project path

Tags: eclipse, gradle

While importing my gradle project in eclipse using gradle(STS) import, the build model fails.

The exception is due to the invalid project path it picks up.

```
* Where:
Build file 'D:\Eclipse_Codebase\trunk\myproject\build.gradle' line: 50

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproject'.
> D:\Softwares\eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\src\com\....g.substitution
```

Now my project is at some other location from where I am importing it, but why does eclipse use this location of where the eclipse is installed and assumes the project to be present there?

Can I specify the project path somewhere so that eclipse uses that or make a change so that it picks the projects default dir?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to import multi gradle project or single gradle project? If you are trying with multi gradle project all your sub projects should be in your root directory of grdale project.

I hope this link will help you .
http://docs.spring.io/sts/docs/2.9.0.old/reference/html/gradle/gradle-sts-tutorial.html

Comment: Its a single gradle project.

Comment: Any other good plugins I can use for gradle in eclipse? Seems like STS won't work in my case